# How to print all the combinations N can be writen as the sum of 1, 3 and 4

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I need to print out the different ways a number N can be illustrated as a sum of 1,3,4.

for example n=5:

- 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
- 1 + 4
- 4 + 1
- 1 + 1 + 3
- 1 + 3 + 1
- 3 + 1 + 1

I am using a dynamic programing solution to find the number of possible ways n can be written as a the sum of 1,3,4

```py
    for i in range(4, n + 1): 
        DP[i] = DP[i - 1] + DP[i - 3] + DP[i - 4] 

    return DP[n]
```

which works and I get the number of possible ways that N can be expressed, 6 in this case, but I am not sure how to print out all the different ways:

- 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
- 1 + 4
- 4 + 1
- 1 + 1 + 3
- 1 + 3 + 1
- 3 + 1 + 1

any suggestions are more than welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This recursive generator will produce the actual combinations:

```
def combis(n):
    if n < 0:
        return
    if n == 0:
        yield []
    for x in (1, 3, 4):
        for combi in combis(n-x):
            yield [x] + combi

>>> list(combis(5))
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 3], [1, 3, 1], [1, 4], [3, 1, 1], [4, 1]]
```

This, of course, is not DP, but a simple uncached and unperformant recursive implementation. But it should guide the way to a DP solution.